# Angular state navigation - add querystring to URL

Tags: angularjs, query-string, router

My application when starts can automatically navigate to a specified state like this:

```
localhost://start.html#/case
```

When a user navigates to this state some parameters are prepared internally to get specific data for templates shown in case state. I need to be able to have an URL with querystring added to the URL in order for the user to copy and paste it into his email or somewhere else. Something like this:

```
    localhost://start.html?project=1234#/case
```

I have spent a considerable time trying to make it work. I tried

```
$location.search('project', '1234');
```

But could not get an URL that would actually work.

Please help me with this task.

Thanks

Comment: what routing service are you using? routeProvider or stateprovider (ui-router)?

Comment: I am using $stateProvider to create my states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can add the parameters at the end of the url

```
localhost://start.html#/case?project=1234
```

then you can get the parameters in angular using $location

```
var projectId = $location.search().project;
// or
var projectId = $location.search('project');
// clear url
$location.search('project', null);
```

Comment: How do I add them to the end of the url?

Comment: how you are adding the parameteres internally?? please paste the code, sorry my delay